# Does Ukrainian have a term for "wet bar"?

Tags: from-english, іменники

Does Ukrainian have a term for [wet bar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wet_bar)?

(I searched http://sum.in.ua/ for the term but that didn't turn up anything.)

Comment: Give more info about «wet bar» like description, and have you try to find the translation.

Comment: He is a description, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wet_bar

Comment: I searched http://sum.in.ua/ for the term but that didn't turn up anything.

Answer (score 1):

Not officially, no. There may be an adaptation or a slang word, but I am not aware of such.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond with a sound and sensible answer.

Comment: @Яша and what other answer did you expect? It's a very niche term, no wonder there's no direct translation.

Comment: My expectations were low. The response from Viktor M was more helpful than this one. But thank you for taking the time to respond.